# biblatex: How can I get \citetitle to be registered in the ibidtracker?

Tags: biblatex, citing

In `biblatex` author-title, I use `\citetitle` to refer to dictionaries I cite often: when citing the *Oxford English Dictionary*, for instance, you don't want to have to print an editor alongside the title at every citation, as is done in short form citations.

However, `\citetitle` doesn't seem to be tracked by `ibidtracker`, so there's a risk of false ibids. How can I include `\citetitle` events in the `ibidtracker` count?

(Alternative ways of citing just the title of a work, or some custom shorthand, are also welcome.)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-ibid,ibidtracker=strict]{biblatex}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{filecontents}{book.bib}
@Book{nussbaum,
  sorttitle   = {Aristotle's De Motu Animalium},
  author      = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title       = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  publisher   = {Princeton University Press},
  location    = {Princeton},
  date        = {1978},
}

@reference{onp,
   editor = {Helle Degnboll},
   title = {A Dictionary of Old Norse Prose},
   shorttitle = {ONP},
   location = {Copenhagen},
   publisher = {Den arnemagnæanske kommission},
   date = {1989/}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{book.bib}

\begin{document}

Statement one\footnote{\cite[55]{nussbaum}; \citetitle[s.v. \mkbibquote{hestr}]{onp}.}, 
statement two\autocite[but this entry should not read \emph{ibid.}]{nussbaum}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Ibid demonstration]
<sub>(source: [langeslag.org](http://langeslag.org/images/sx/citetitle-ibid.png))</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard definition of the `\citetitle`/`\citeyear`/`\citeauthor` commands include the line `\boolfalse{citetracker}%` which turns off the ibidtracker temporarily, so we can re-enable it by commenting out that particular line

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {%\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-ibid, ibidtracker=strict]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {%\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}    

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{nussbaum,
  sorttitle   = {Aristotle's De Motu Animalium},
  author      = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title       = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  publisher   = {Princeton University Press},
  location    = {Princeton},
  date        = {1978},
}
@reference{onp,
   editor     = {Helle Degnboll},
   title      = {A Dictionary of Old Norse Prose},
   shorttitle = {ONP},
   location   = {Copenhagen},
   publisher  = {Den arnemagnæanske kommission},
   date       = {1989/},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Statement one\footnote{\cite[55]{nussbaum}; \citetitle[s.v. \mkbibquote{hestr}]{onp}.}, 
statement two\autocite[but this entry should not read \emph{ibid.}]{nussbaum}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In your particular case though, I would rather use `shorthand` and `\cite` instead of `shorttitle` and `\citetitle`.

```
@reference{onp,
   editor    = {Helle Degnboll},
   title     = {A Dictionary of Old Norse Prose},
   shorthand = {ONP},
   location  = {Copenhagen},
   publisher = {Den arnemagnæanske kommission},
   date      = {1989/},
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-ibid, ibidtracker=strict]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{nussbaum,
  sorttitle   = {Aristotle's De Motu Animalium},
  author      = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title       = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  publisher   = {Princeton University Press},
  location    = {Princeton},
  date        = {1978},
}
@reference{onp,
   editor    = {Helle Degnboll},
   title     = {A Dictionary of Old Norse Prose},
   shorthand = {ONP},
   location  = {Copenhagen},
   publisher = {Den arnemagnæanske kommission},
   date      = {1989/},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Statement one\autocites[55]{nussbaum}[s.v. \mkbibquote{hestr}]{onp}, 
statement two\autocite[but this entry should not read \emph{ibid.}]{nussbaum}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for recommending `shorthand`. However, a more concise way of citing for "Statement one" is `Statement one\autocites[55]{nussbaum}[s.v. \mkbibquote{hestr}]{onp},`.